# date updated as many times, should not created another entry for date in DB

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

```
Models.py   
 class FreezePrimaryCategory(models.Model):
    freeze_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.freeze_date)
```

Views.py

```
class FreezePrimaryCategory(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @checkToken
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        freeze_date = request.data.get("freeze_date")
        data = {
            'freeze_date': freeze_date,
        }
        serializer = FreezeCategorySerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializers.py

class FreezeCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = FreezePrimaryCategory
fields = ['freeze_date']

```
def validate(self, data):
    today = date.today()

    if data['freeze_date'] >= today:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Date cannot be greater than current Date')
    return data
```

I want date api entry in db should be only once and updated as many times.

Comment: So do you want POST api to create first and update after that?

Comment: yes, first create date for that api and for second time and many times same api hit update date

Comment: Then you need to use PUT or PATCH method for update.